# Error when playing video. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'play')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a video gallery with videos that are being mapped through. I'm having trouble playing one video at a time. Instead, i get the error, `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'play')`. I think its because the function is asnyc and i changed the play function to async/await. Still doesn't work. This format works with one video but not multiple.

I want to be able to play the video and

```
export default function VideoGallery() {
  const [videoData, setVideoData] = useState([]);
  const [showControls, setShowControls] = useState(false);
  const vidRef = useRef();

  //bunch of code

  const playVideo = async (e) => {
    await vidRef.current.play();
    setShowControls(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative w-full p-1 group">
      <div className=" flex flex-wrap -m-1 md:-m-2 ">
        {videoData.map((data) => {
          const videoURL = data.videoURL.replace(
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com",
            ""
          );
          return (
            <>
              <div
                key={data.videoURL}
                className="relative flex w-full md:w-1/3 sm:w-1/2 flex-wrap group"
              >
                <div className="relative w-full p-1 group">
                  <video
                    src=...
                    preload="metadata"
                    volume="true"
                    controls={showControls ? "controls" : ""}
                    controlsList="nodownload"
                    refs={vidRef}
                  />
                  <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2">
                    <BsPlayCircle
                      className="text-[#fa9204] text-6xl cursor-pointer"
                      onClick={playVideo}
                      refs={vidRef}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do we have property called **refs** in react?

Comment: @CodeThing, there actually is. I just thought that its a plural to ref which would make sense since i'm looking through videos but i'm probably wrong. More importantly, with "ref" or "refs", i get an error either way.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. Please share if you have any references so that i can learn something new.

Comment: Its part of the legacy docs for react. I hope that counts. https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This format works with one video but not multiple.* Obviously it will work for only one because you are assigning ref in loop. So ref will override for each iteration.

Moreover it is not working, because you are assigning refs to multiple element in single iteration. Video element as well as Play button element.

Please check below solution, I have made slight changes into it. Now ref will be array and we can access it using indexes. Hope this solution helps!

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function VideoGallery() {
  const [videoData, setVideoData] = useState([]);
  const [showControls, setShowControls] = useState(false);
  const vidRef = useRef([]);

  const playVideo = (index) => {
    vidRef.current[index].play();
    setShowControls(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative w-full p-1 group">
      <div className=" flex flex-wrap -m-1 md:-m-2 ">
        {videoData.map((data, i) => (
          <div
            key={data.videoURL}
            className="relative flex w-full md:w-1/3 sm:w-1/2 flex-wrap group"
          >
            <div className="relative w-full p-1 group">
              <video
                width="250px"
                src={data.videoURL}
                preload="metadata"
                volume="true"
                controls={showControls ? "controls" : ""}
                controlsList="nodownload"
                ref={el => vidRef.current.push(el)}
              />
              <div className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 -translate-x-1/2">
                <BsPlayCircle
                  className="text-[#fa9204] text-6xl cursor-pointer"
                  onClick={() => playVideo(i)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```